# Chef Vault user creation

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is there a way to override chef-vault from creating users alphabetically?

In order words, if i have a user alf,bob,cain and dave in my vault, is it possible to have user cain get created before alf?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

The admins of a vault are always displayed as a sorted list:

```
$ knife vault show secrets app1 -p admins
admins:
  alf
  bob
  cain
  dave
id:     app1
..
..
```

But why should that matter functionally? When accessing the vault each admin user or chef node will be authenticating once, using their private key.

And users are not created per se. The vault is simple updated with a new list of admins. It assumes that the users already exist, otherwise an error will be thrown:

```
$ knife vault update secrets app1 -A 'alf,bob,cain,dave,onemore' 
$ knife vault show secrets app1 -p admins
admins:
  alf
  bob
  cain
  dave
  onemore
id:     app1
..
..
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. The reason why i want user cain created before Alf is because user alf's home directory is a subdirectory of user cain. I cannot change these user names unfortunately/

Comment: @jebjeb That doesn't make sense. Why should the home directory matter? Are you trying to create users from data stored within a vault? (As opposed to the admins with access to the vault as I explained above).