# knife vault show vaultname not showing all users

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-vault

I have created 7 users in my vault however i am only able to view 5 of them when i do a `knife vault show vaultname`.

When i do a `knife data bag show vaultname`, i see all 7 users plus their corresponding user_keys items.

I am also able to see the all seven users being created when i run `chef-client` on my nodes.

I am currently running chefserver version 11.2.

Does anyone have an idea why i am only able to see 5 users when i run `knife vault show vaultname` ?

---

EDIT

Content of my vault

```
$ knife vault show users user1

action:                  create
comment:                 User1
create_home:             true
dbpass:                  xxxxxxx
delete_home_when_remove: true
gid:                     user1
groups:
  user1
  user2
home:                    /home/user1
id:                      user1
password:                $6$tMb7XUou$9pTFWIlGbKJoT8FApDQSvjrRivnpB/tzRr/XrAX8qcdncO.OySKXCuAXxaSDPdQLlj4HGMRqvghvj24zM4XCx.
setfacl:                 false
shell:                   /bin/bash
ssh_keys:                ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAnOfRTKLEsUcY/0YNcJWoTq0OMQ1VbrcN4bEoqrN3cPbjCD0CcjZQKdiM9x+eD+usVbBsswG6LtE57dvM0+9tdidr0PfzK6iZ1ttv/cpnfi7Q3kKSlY4kK117ZhK2iKnLSpSMV1xPy97UDxkJK1NmC9FJpxtDmg5vqSTvmTmbs1auimehU3f3+db5g7lSXjI52jHM9xbdwONFK6yhgl2+iiC6A7AesdLT407p4S0nC6VlMcAKue1jvr0eQUK//Yqtp/APLflyQQ== 
sudo_pwdless:            true
sudoer:                  true
username:                user1
```

CHEF RECIPE

```
chef_gem 'chef-vault' do
  compile_time true if respond_to?(:compile_time)
end

require 'chef-vault'

if node['testcook']['use_databag'] == true then
        users = data_bag(node['testcook']['databag_name']).delete_if {|x| x.include? "_keys" }
        sudoer_users = Array.new()
        users.each do |id|
              user = ChefVault::Item.load(node['testcook']['databag_name'], id)
              testcook user['id'] do
                 comment user['comment'] unless user['comment'].nil?
                 groups user['groups'] unless user['groups'].nil?
                 home user['home'] unless user['home'].nil?
                 create_home user['create_home'] unless user['create_home'].nil?
                 gid user['gid'] unless user['gid'].nil?
                 shell user['shell'] unless user['shell'].nil?
                 password user['password'] unless user['password'].nil?
                 uid user['uid'] unless user['uid'].nil?
                 ssh_keys user['ssh_keys'] unless user['ssh_keys'].nil?
                 delete_home_when_remove user['delete_home_when_remove'] unless user['delete_home_when_remove'].nil?
                 if user['action'] == 'remove'
                         action :remove
                 elsif
                        action :create
                 else
                         action :nothing
                end
         end
         if user['sudoer']
                 command = user['command'] ? user['command'] : 'ALL'
                 hash = { :uname => user['id'], :command => command, :sudo_pwdless => user['sudo_pwdless'] }
                 sudoer_users.push(hash)
         end
    end
else
    sudoer_users = Array.new()
    users = data_bag(node['testcook']['databag_name']).delete_if {|x| x.include? "_keys" }
    node.default['testcook']['databag_name'].each_line do |user|
    users.each do |id|
    user = ChefVault::Item.load(node['testcook']['databag_name'], id)
         testcook user['id'] do
                   comment user['comment'] unless user['comment'].nil?
                   groups user['groups'] unless user['groups'].nil?
                   home user['home'] unless user['home'].nil?
                   create_home user['create_home'] unless user['create_home'].nil?
                   shell user['shell'] unless user['shell'].nil?
                   password user['password'] unless user['password'].nil?
                   uid user['uid'] unless user['uid'].nil?
                   gid user['gid'] unless user['gid'].nil?
                   ssh_keys user['ssh_keys'] unless user['ssh_keys'].nil?
                   delete_home_when_remove user['delete_home_when_remove'] unless user['delete_home_when_remove'].nil?
                   if user['action'] == 'remove' then
                           action :remove
                   elsif
                          action :create
                   else
                           action :nothing
                   end
            end
            if user['sudoer']
                   command = user['command'] ? user['command'] : 'ALL'
                   hash = { :uname => user['username'], :command => command, :sudo_pwdless => user['sudo_pwdless'] }
                   sudoer_users.push(hash)
            end
      end
  end
end
template "/etc/sudoers" do
         source 'sudoers.erb'
         mode   '0440'
         owner  'root'
         group  node['root_group']
         variables(
                  :sudoers_users     => sudoer_users,
                  :sudoers_groups     =>  node[:testcook][:users][:sudoer_group]
        )
        only_if { sudoer_users }
end
```

Comment: Chef vault does not create users..... Your last question also seemed to be talking about creating users. What are you using vault for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321994/chef-vault-user-creation

Comment: I suspect you're using a chef recipe to create users based on the contents of a Chef vault. If so you need to include a lot more detail, the format of the vault and the code you're using. Otherwise we have no way to understand your problem. Finally have you considered the community users cookbook for managing users? It uses normal data bags, which is perhaps less complicated: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/users

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am using the vault to manage users credentials on my server.  And yes i am using a chef recipe to create the users . I will update the question in a bit with the info u asked of.

Comment: The list of users to be added appears to be found in a node attribute "node['testcook']['databag_name']". I don't understand why you think a "knife vault" command will return information for more than one user. Each user's data in a separate vault. Basically is sounds like it's working as advertised. Finally could I suggest losing the sensitive data (password) and then you could use the simpler "users" community cookbook.

Comment: Just for the record, the only thing in there that's a secret is possibly `dbpass`, everything else doesn't need encryption of any kind.

Comment: @ Mark- A knife vault show users generally displays all the items in the users vault. Our company currently requires us to setup the vault items the way it is which is why the content of each item includes more than just the dbpass.